# How to choose a text color for a logo that has a bi-colored icon in it?

Tags: color, logo, color-theory, critique

So I'm making this logo for a friend's project of an online multiplayer version of the card game "Coup". This is what I made so far:

[image: Logo v1]

But the thing is I don't want to use 3 colors, as I think it makes it confusing in this case. But it also doesn't work to just make the text one of the drawing's colors, so I'm stuck. How should I go about solving this? Should I pick the color pallette again? Maybe make the faces one color?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use color at all? The above looks fine in black and white. See also [Should a logo always work in black and white?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/85781/23061)

Comment: You would likely benefit from reading up on [Resources for learning logo design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/297/23061) and learning the difference between [a logo and wordmarks](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/33643/23061).

Comment: Also, if you're talking about [this Coup game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/131357/coup) it is subject to copyright and your friend *cannot* create his own version called the same thing and market it. Your logo could even be considered copyright infringement.

Comment: It won't be marketed actually.

Comment: Just because you aren't selling it doesn't mean it's not copyright infringement

Comment: I second @ZachSaucier here: if this is being put online and it shares the same principles as the card / board game, expect cease and desist orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already voted as opinion-based, so here's what should be done *in my opinion*:

- black text
- orange icon
- ditch the purple
- recreate the icon so it has one half made of fills, and the other half, of strokes

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea, i like it a lot.